# CGI bin bash script not workin

Tags: html, bash, cgi-bin

I have a bash script in a cgi-bin that is getting an error.  I have another script in the CGI-Bin that works fine.  the script works fine when ran from the server, but does not work when ran from the webpage.  My assumption is CGI-Bin is setting up correctly since the other script runs.  Here is the file level permissions on the file.  I gave the non-working cgi full access to see if it worked.  Stress.cgi work but increase.cgi does not work.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     root     125 Jun  5 00:40 increase.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user  40 Jun  3 16:47 stress.cgi
```

```
#!/bin/bash
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name ##### --max- 
size 4 --output text
```

Comment: Please have a look at the error log

Comment: here is the error [Fri Jun 05 13:10:52.310075 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 32616] [client 10.0.1.51:43368] AH02809: Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /var/www/html/increase.cgi

Comment: The fact that stress.cgi works may not imply that the directory is set correctly for other files. From the error message it seems to try to access a increase.cgi in your DocumentRoot. What URL are you using for stress.cgi ? compare it with the one for increase.cgi. Look trough the configuration and see if there is an alias or a location defined for stress.cgi

Answer (score 0):

The issues was a file permission issue.  Once updated the cgi script worked as desired.